# How to displayvalues in jsp table from sqlserver

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp

I am trying to print values from sql server to jsp table using MVC approach. Following is my function from DAO class

```
public ArrayList<EmployeeBean> checkApplicationStatus() throws SQLException
{
    ArrayList<EmployeeBean> list=new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println("checkappstatus");
    Connection conn = DbCon.getCon();
    PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement("Select empid, ename, designation from Employee");
    ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();

    while (rs.next()) {
        EmployeeBean e1=new EmployeeBean();
        e1.setEmployeeid(rs.getString("empid"));
        System.out.println("id: "+e1.getEmployeeid());

        e1.setEmployeename(rs.getString("ename"));
        System.out.println("id: "+e1.getEmployeename());

        e1.setDesignation(rs.getString("designation"));
        System.out.println("id: "+e1.getDesignation());

        list.add(e1);
      }
    for(EmployeeBean s:list){
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    return list;
    }
```

The problem is only the last record from sql table gets added in the list. How do i insert all my table records to arraylist.

Comment: Did you try to debug your code at server side and check what values are added in list? **Note:** Make sure you close your connection at the end.

Comment: As i said only the values from last record are added in list.

Comment: How many times your while loop is getting iterated?

Comment: I have 2 records in the table so the loop is getting iterated 2 times

Comment: And how did you check that only 1 record is inserted in your `ArrayList`?

Comment: The table in my sql server has 2 records and 3 columns. So the same things should be inserted in the list right but my list contains 2 records but only of the last record from sql.

Comment: @KunalChaubal Please debug the code ..its hard to everyone to tell what exactly wrong with code .

Comment: @KunalChaubal, you can edit your question and add where you found only 1 record is getting inserted in your  ArrayList.

Comment: @KunalChaubal, Can you show how you checked the value inside list ?